# how to test python's "__main__" codes with nose

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose

for codes like in a some.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # ...
  args = parser.parse_args()
  foo()
```

I'm using nosetests --with-coverage to collect results. but the '**main**' codes are not covered, how to test codes here, or omit nose coverage?

Comment: You have coverage for `foo()` right? That's all that the `__main__` section does, anyway.

Comment: thanks, I forgot add note in __main__, argparse related codes

Comment: Well, then, put that out into its own function and call it from your `__main__` block...